# ImportError: cannot import name requests while installing Tensorflow

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, windows-10, anaconda

I have installed Anaconda2 on my windows 10 with python 2.7.15 version. Now, I need to install tensorflow and Keras, however, I am consistently getting the error while installing using "conda" or "pip". I googled it a lot about this error, but to no avail. Please help me out in finding the lead to resolving this issue. TIA, Priya Arora

The stack trace is as below:

```
(base) C:\Users\ARORAP1\anaconda2>conda install jupyter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ARORAP1\anaconda2\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 10, in <module
>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\ARORAP1\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 11
3, in main
    return conda_exception_handler(_main, *args)
  File "C:\Users\ARORAP1\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line
1112, in conda_exception_handler
    return_value = exception_handler(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ARORAP1\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line
822, in __call__
    return self.handle_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\ARORAP1\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line
864, in handle_exception
    return self.handle_unexpected_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\ARORAP1\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line
876, in handle_unexpected_exception
    self.print_unexpected_error_report(error_report)
  File "C:\Users\ARORAP1\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line
947, in print_unexpected_error_report
    from .cli.main_info import get_env_vars_str, get_main_info_str
  File "C:\Users\ARORAP1\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_info.py", li
ne 25, in <module>
    from ..core.subdir_data import SubdirData
  File "C:\Users\ARORAP1\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\core\subdir_data.py",
 line 28, in <module>
    from ..core.package_cache_data import PackageCacheData
  File "C:\Users\ARORAP1\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\core\package_cache_da
ta.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .path_actions import CacheUrlAction, ExtractPackageAction
  File "C:\Users\ARORAP1\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\core\path_actions.py"
, line 25, in <module>
    from ..gateways.connection.download import download
  File "C:\Users\ARORAP1\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\connection\_
_init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests import ConnectionError, HTTPError, Session
  File "C:\Users\ARORAP1\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\__init
__.py", line 83, in <module>
    from pip._internal.compat import WINDOWS
  File "C:\Users\ARORAP1\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py",
 line 42, in <module>
    from pip._internal import cmdoptions
  File "C:\Users\ARORAP1\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cmdoptions.py
", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index import (
  File "C:\Users\ARORAP1\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", li
ne 15, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests, six
ImportError: cannot import name requests

(base) C:\Users\ARORAP1\anaconda2>
```

Comment: is your pip version updated? try updating pip install --upgrade